# How to display sum of values in local-storage?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, angular-local-storage

I have local-storage values in below :

```
[{"id":1, "amount":24000000}, {"id":2, "amount":10000000}]
```

How to sum amount values in local-storage?. I display my local-storage in jsp using AngularJS.

My controller :

```
$scope.listOfCart = CartService.getAllCarts()||[];
$scope.items = $scope.listOfCart
```

My jsp :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="cart in items">
    <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then how to display sum values amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you need to calculate the total amount inside the **controller**.

Here use the `totalAmount` variable in the **HTML** to display the total amount.

**Controller**

```
$scope.listOfCart = CartService.getAllCarts()||[];
$scope.items = $scope.listOfCart;
$scope.totalAmount = 0;
$scope.items.forEach(function(item){
    $scope.totalAmount += item.amount;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="cart in items">
    <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
</tr>

Total Amount: {{totalAmount}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming the array of data from local storage is in `$scope.items`.

In which case you can set a new `amount` to the scope that is build by using `reduce` to iteratively sum the values from the items.

```
$scope.amount = $scope.items.reduce((result, item) => {
  return item['amount'] + result;
}, 0);
```

Which in this case would give the result `34000000`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through listOfCart and calculate sum of amount once you recieve data from your CartService.

```
   $scope.sumAmount = 0;
   angular.forEach($scope.listOfCart , function(value, key){
       $scope.sumAmount = $scope.sumAmount + value.amount;
   });
```

and in your html

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="cart in items">
    <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
</tr>
Total : {{sumAmount}}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It's work. All answer like your answer

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

In html:

```
<td>{{sumValues()}}</td>
```

In controller

```
$scope.sumValues= function(){
    var sum= 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.listOfCart , function(value, key){
        sum += value.amount;
    });
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it's work. All answer like your answer.

Comment: Mark it up,If it's helpful.